# How to search through arraylist of arraylists / polymorphic array

Tags: java, object, arraylist, return, polymorphism

I am working on a graded assignment, the software contains multiple product types, electronic, book etc,  each with their own arraylist, each arraylist is stored in a master array list. I am trying to use a find method to return the correct type of object from its respective arraylist, e.g if user input is 'food', and 'milk', it knows to search the 'food' arraylist, and then compare the string 'milk' to the name attribute of each object in the 'food' arraylist.

However I am struggling as the software is returning an object object and not a foodproduct object.

The arraylist of arraylists is created as follows:

```
public class ProductList {
private ArrayList<ArrayList>Products = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();    
private String Filename;    

public ProductList(){
Products.add(new ArrayList<ElectronicProduct>());
Products.add(new ArrayList<KitchenProduct>());
Products.add(new ArrayList<FoodProduct>());
Products.add(new ArrayList<BookProduct>());
Filename = "ProductList.txt";
}
```

Products are added to the correct arraylist with the following add method, it has superclass product objects passed in the argument, however I try to convert these to the required subclass before adding to the respective array:

```
public void add(String category,Product src) throws IOException{

switch(category){

    case "Electronic":
    Products.get(0).add(src instanceof ElectronicProduct);
    break;

    case "Kitchen":
    Products.get(1).add(src instanceof KitchenProduct);
    break;

    case "Food":
    Products.get(2).add(src instanceof FoodProduct);
    break;

    case "Book":
    Products.get(3).add(src instanceof BookProduct);
    break;

      }    
}
```

To retrieve the objects I have the following method, this is where the issue becomes apparent although it may be caused by an earlier method.

It gives the error 'Object cannot be converted to electronic product'.

```
public Product find(String categoryInput, String nameInput){

switch(categoryInput){

    case "Electronic":
    //this does not work
    for(ElectronicProduct product : this.Products.get(0)); 
    // code to compare the nameInput would be here          
    break;

    case "Kitchen":
     //same as above
    break;

    case "Food":
   //same as above
    break;

    case "Book":
    //same as above
    break;

}
```

Please could someone help me identify where this is going wrong, and suggest how to solve it?

**EDIT**

Following Steve Wakefords suggestion I changed

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList>Products = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
```

to

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Product>> Products = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Product>>();
```

However it is now causing an error here:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create Electronic/Food as a child class/extension of Object.

Comment: The electronic/food classes are extensions of a class called product.

Answer (score 0):

For ProuductList try:

```
public class ProductList {
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<? extends Product>> Products = new ArrayList<>(); 
    private String Filename;    

    public ProductList() {
        Products.add(new ArrayList<ElectronicProduct>());
        Products.add(new ArrayList<KitchenProduct>());
        Products.add(new ArrayList<FoodProduct>());
        Products.add(new ArrayList<BookProduct>());
        Filename = "ProductList.txt";
    }
}
```

You were using the non generic type on the inner ArrayList which is why it is giving objects instead of Products.

When adding: the instanceof operator returns true/false. You are looking for *casting* which is `(ElectronicProduct)src`, but I don't think you need it, src is probably fine.

When retrieving: You probably have to get a Product and cast it...

```
for (Product product : this.Products.get(0)) {
    // (ElectronicProduct)product
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help with this, I did not realise instanceof was a boolean!

I have used your initial suggestion however it is giving an error when initialising the sub arrays, the error is in the edit, do you know why this may be?

Comment: Does ElectronicProduct Extend Product?

Comment: yes, all of the classes seen ElectronicProduct, FoodProduct, BookProduct, all extend Product.. I did try writing Products.add(new ArrayList<ElectronicProduct extends Product>()); but this did not work.

Comment: Products.add(new ArrayList<ElectronicProduct<? extends Product> electronicProduct>());

Comment: This is what I have tried but i am getting the message it is not syntactically correct, do you know what must be modified? Thank you so much for your help with this, it really is appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207220/discussion-between-steve-wakeford-and-initialisingattributes).